# Continuous music playing on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a website which requires continuous music playing even between switching pages.  I know I can do this with frames but that would be too detrimental to the site in general.

This website seems to be able to allow you to play music, browse around the URLs update to reflect the page you are on:

http://www.beatport.com/

Does anybody know this would be achieved?

Many thanks

Comment: The question title cracked me up :D That's something I would hate to start my day with! "We've got continuous music playing on our website, wtf"

Comment: Frames are like drugs, just say no to them

Comment: `title + iframe != usability`

Comment: @karim79 There are plenty of reasons you might want continuous music playing between page loads.  Beatport is a good example.  I think continuous music play is often confused with unwanted auto-start music but it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the URL changes as you navigate around, you aren't actually navigating from page to page on BeatPort. They're using HTML5's History API, particularly `pushState`, to update the URL in the browser when doing AJAX page loads.

Comment: You can see this in Firebug or Webkit Inspector, by the way.